# Create New List from List of [String] in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Assuming I have a list like this

```
let a =[["Warning:","Route","1543","must","Stop","on","Link","11881"],["Warning:","Route","1578","must","Stop","on","Link","12171"]]
```

And I want to extract third element of each list inside it, i.e I want to get the resultant as `["1543","1578"]`

I wrote the following piece of code for obtaining it, but it is not working:

```
foldr (\acc x -> (x !! 2):acc) [] a
```

Comment: `map (!! 2)` would suffice

Comment: Ok, thanks :-). That's very clean. But why isn't the above code working?

Comment: Also, `foldr` works too, but it requires other order of arguments: `foldr (\x acc -> (x !! 2):acc) [] a`.

Comment: You should be careful while using the above solution as it can totally break when any sublist contains less than 3 elements. A solution using `Maybe` is a more safer choice.

Comment: Like Satvik said, this is not particularly safe regardless of how you implement it. It might be best to not create those nested lists at all, but use a specialised `data` type and write a nice parser with e.g. [parsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec) – but it would probably be overkill; if this is just for a one-time script then `map (!! 2)` is positively fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a safe way to do what you want to do using a [list comprehension](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#im-a-list-comprehension) and [pattern matching](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#pattern-matching)

```
let a' = [x | (_:(_:(x:_))) <- a]
```

This will iterate over the list `a`, look at all sublists of length at least `3`, and return the third element of each such sublist.

This solution will silently ignore sublists of length less than `3`. To work around this, and gain some flexibility, you can write a function that uses `Maybe` in its return type; if the list has a third element, it will return `Just` the third element, otherwise it will return `Nothing`.

```
takeThird :: [a] -> Maybe a
takeThird (_:(_:(x:_))) = Just x
takeThird _             = Nothing
```

Then, you can write a safe version of your operation using a list comprehension:

```
let safea = [takeThird x | x <- a]
```

And from that you can create a version that may drop elements:

```
let maybedropa = [x | Just x <- safea]
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution using the recent [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) library (Control.lens) would:

```
import Control.Lens
>a^..traverse.(element 2)
["1543","1578"]
```

Not using the infix notation:

```
>toListOf (traverse.(element 2)) a
["1543","1578"]
```

'traverse' visits each element of a traversable, in this case the list, and (element 2) grabs the element with the 2 index and toListOf gathers it all into a list. This method has the advantage that if decide to complicate your data structure later you just need to write your own lens interface to it if it does not already have one.

Let say instead of a [[String]] you have [[(Annotation, String)]] and you just want the String portion just like above.  Then all you need to do is the _2 tuple accessor.

```
a^..traverse.(element 2)._2
```